# Laravel Nova - Data missing on save a new register

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I have some datetime fields in my model and when I try to save a new register, works fine, but when I set the `$casts` attribute for dates (because it's required for laravel nova), I can save new register, show up in database, but returns the error below and don't redirect for the index page.

I'm using SQLServer, the fields are the format datetime, like "Y-m-d H:i:s.000"

```
"message": "Data missing",
    "exception": "InvalidArgumentException",
    "file": "/var/www/vendor/nesbot/carbon/src/Carbon/Traits/Creator.php",
    "line": 537,
```

I tried all kind of date formats for my
`$cast` and doesn't works , I tried to set `$dateFormat` to "Y-m-d H:i:s" or "Y-m-d H:i:s.000" or "Y-m-d H:i:s.u" or "Y-m-d H:i:s.v" and doesn't works.

```
//My Model

<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class QuickQuiz extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Attributes
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */

    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    protected $casts = [
        'start_date' => 'datetime:Y-m-d H:i:s',
        'end_date' => 'datetime:Y-m-d H:i:s',
        'draw_date' => 'datetime:Y-m-d H:i:s',
    ];

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Boot
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */
    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::creating(function ($quickQuiz) {

            $quickQuiz->uuid = Str::uuid();
            $quickQuiz->status_id = Status::pendent();

            $quickQuiz->created_user_id = auth()->user()->id;
            $quickQuiz->updated_user_id = auth()->user()->id;

        });

        static::updating(function ($quickQuiz) {
            $quickQuiz->updated_user_id = auth()->user()->id;

        });
    }

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Relationships
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    */

    public function questions()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(QuickQuizQuestion::class);
    }

    public function createdUser()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'created_user_id', 'id');
    }

    public function updatedUser()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'updated_user_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

```
//Example of register

[
  {
    "id": 47,
    "uuid": "f8c70e31-5a49-4587-aabe-e08286060e62",
    "title": "Nunc iaculis posuere nibh, a vehicula arcu malesuada eget.",
    "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed tortor dolor, interdum at nunc et, congue iaculis felis. Nulla ultrices lorem a ex sagittis tempor. Morbi lacinia ante mi. Quisque feugiat lectus eget nisi bibendum faucibus. Vivamus ex quam, convallis eu elit vitae, cursus lobortis diam. Nullam vel placerat ex, eget lacinia mi. Nulla lorem tortor, tincidunt eu scelerisque vel, faucibus semper lacus. Nulla ut felis eget ipsum blandit elementum lacinia id mi. Maecenas imperdiet non felis a tincidunt. Pellentesque tempus tincidunt enim sed fermentum. Nunc iaculis posuere nibh, a vehicula arcu malesuada eget.",
    "start_date": "2019-04-18 09:15:15.000",
    "end_date": "2019-04-30 17:15:15.000",
    "max_response_time": 45,
    "status_id": 5,
    "winner_clerk_id": null,
    "prize_value": 111.11,
    "draw_date": null,
    "created_user_id": 1,
    "updated_user_id": 1,
    "created_at": "2019-04-09 14:56:08.497",
    "updated_at": "2019-04-09 14:56:08.497",
    "deleted_at": null
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try casting the date as 'Y-m-d H:i:s.u0' like this:

```
protected $casts = [
   'start_date' => 'datetime:Y-m-d H:i:s.u0',
   'end_date' => 'datetime:Y-m-d H:i:s.u0',
   'draw_date' => 'datetime:Y-m-d H:i:s.u0',
];
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with SQLServer.
Try to define [mutators for these attributes](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-a-mutator) in your model

```
/**
 * @var string
 */
protected $dateFormat = 'Y-m-d H:i:s.v';

/**
 * @param $value
 */
public function setStartDateAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['start_date'] = null !== $value ? date($this->dateFormat, strtotime($value)) : null;
}

/**
 * @param $value
 */
public function setEndDateAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['end_date'] = null !== $value ? date($this->dateFormat, strtotime($value)) : null;
}

/**
 * @param $value
 */
public function setDrawDateAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['draw_date'] = null !== $value ? date($this->dateFormat, strtotime($value)) : null;
}
```